# Why python UDF returns unexpected datetime objects where as the same function applied over RDD gives proper datetime object

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong so pardon me if this looks naive,
My problem is reproducible by the following data

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = sc.parallelize([Row(C3=u'Dec  1 2013 12:00AM'),
 Row(C3=u'Dec  1 2013 12:00AM'),
 Row(C3=u'Dec  5 2013 12:00AM')]).toDF()
```

I have created a function to parse this date strings as datetime objects to process further

```
from datetime import datetime
def date_convert(date_str):
   date_format = '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p'
   try:
    dt=datetime.strptime(date_str,date_format)
   except ValueError,v:
    if len(v.args) > 0 and v.args[0].startswith('unconverted data remains: '):
      dt = dt[:-(len(v.args[0])-26)]
      dt=datetime.strptime(dt,date_format)
    else:
      raise v
   return dt
```

Now if I make a UDF out of this and apply to my dataframe I get unexpected data

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
date_convert_udf = udf(date_convert)
df.select(date_convert_udf(df.C3).alias("datetime")).take(2)
```

The result is like below

```
Out[40]: 
[Row(datetime=u'java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=2013,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]'),
 Row(datetime=u'java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=2013,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=0,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]')]
```

but if I use it after making the dataframe a RDD then it returns a pythond datetime object

```
df.rdd.map(lambda row:date_convert(row.C3)).collect()
(1) Spark Jobs
Out[42]: 
[datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 5, 0, 0)]
```

I want to achieve the similar thing with dataframe . How can I do that and what is wrong with this approach (UDF over dataframe)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's because you have to set the return type data of your `UDF`. Apparently you are trying to obtain `timestamps`, if this is the case you have to write something like this.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
date_convert_udf = udf(date_convert, TimestampType())
```

Comment: I love you Alberto!! Thank you!